# MIT thesis: change bibliography to IEEE style

Tags: bibliographies, citing, ieee-style

I'm using MIT thesis template downloaded from here http://web.mit.edu/thesis/tex/

My question is how to change the bibliography style to IEEE style in bibtex? Thanks.

An example in IEEE format:

M. M. Bronstein, J. Bruna, Y. LeCun, A. Szlam, and P. Vandergheynst,
“Geometric deep learning: Going beyond Euclidean data,” IEEE Signal
Processing Magazine, vol. 34, pp. 18–42, July 2017.

Comment: The template doesn't work for me out of the box (error: `Emergency stop. process all files:}`. Could you please add a working MWE. Have you tried to use the ([IEEEtran.bst](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex?lang=en)) template

Comment: @vogs: Please comment the following part: \typein [\files]{Enter file names to process, (chap1,chap2 ...), or `all' to
%process all files:}
%\def\all{all}
%\ifx\files\all \typeout{Including all files.} \else \typeout{Including only \files.} \includeonly{\files} \fi

Comment: I did this, I furthermore had the issue that the references used in the text are not present in the `main.bib` file. I used the ones which were available, e.g. `\cite{phdthesis-full}` and it looks good for me.

Comment: @Steradiant: Is the reference in IEEE style?

Comment: Please provide a picture how you want it to look like

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: It looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/zSpzV1c)

Comment: The one you provided is not IEEE format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [IEEEtran](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex?lang=en) template. This code

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{mitthesis}
\usepackage{lgrind}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

text \cite{article-crossref}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

delivers the IEEE style citation.

The `main.bib` file contains:

```
@ARTICLE{7974879,
  author={M. M. {Bronstein} and J. {Bruna} and Y. {LeCun} and A. {Szlam} and P. {Vandergheynst}},
  journal={IEEE Signal Processing Magazine}, 
  title={Geometric Deep Learning: Going beyond Euclidean data}, 
  year={2017},
  volume={34},
  number={4},
  pages={18-42},}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually a few minutes ago, I just resolved the case. However, thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

A new MIT thesis template was released in 2023: https://ctan.org/pkg/mitthesis.

This new latex template can use either `biber` or `bibtex` with any available bibliography style, but the default as distributed is `biber` with the `IEEE` style.